# Searching a string in Excel column and matching cell moved to another column

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

Looking for help.
  I've data in column A in Excel (2010) and search string in Column B. In case a cell in Column A constrains the search string of Column B, then need to move (or copy) corresponding cell content in Column A to Column C.
  Thanks

Column A
bacd@hotmail.com
abc@excel.com
people@superuser.com

Column B- Search String
excel
superuser

Column C (expected like)
abc@excel.com
people@superuser.com

Comment: Row 1 in Column C will be empty whereas 2nd and 3rd row will be "abc@excel.com" and "people@superuser.com"?

Comment: Yes Sir. C1 is empty. Basically, if matching cell is A3, the content of A3 need to be in C3.

Comment: Will column b be populated for all rows in column a? In your example, column a has three rows whereas column b has 2 rows. Did you ignore rows 1 of column b because it is empty?

Comment: Column will NOT be populated for all rows in column a. row 1 I left for Heading. we can ignore row 1 for all columns

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be easiest to use VBA [instr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8460tsh1(v=vs.90).aspx)

Roughing it out, this should work -

```
Sub Lokam()
Dim a As Range
Dim b As Range
For Each a In Range("A:A")
    If a = "" Then Exit Sub
    For Each b In Range("B:B")
        If b = "" Then GoTo yay:
            If InStr(a, b) > 0 Then
                a.Offset(, 2) = a
            End If

    Next
yay:
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for Macro. My requirement is search in Column A and place matching content in corresponding cell in column C. Another one I see is macro not "exit"ing - looping forever - Thanks

Comment: Also,
  InStr(b, c) > 0 not happening... even match string exists 
 
Watch : + : b : "excel" : Range/Range : Module1.Lokam
Watch : + : c : "abc@excel.com" : Range/Range : Module1.Lokam
Watch :   : InStr(b, c) : 0 : Variant/Long : Module1.Lokam

Comment: @Lokam you can adjust the macro to fit your data. I've updated it.

Comment: Thank you Sir. It worked for me :) – appreciated
__ Lokam

Comment: @Lokam if your problem is solved, be sure to mark it as complete by clicking the checkmark next to the answer that helped you.